# An object with extra keys is getting flagged as invalid, even though an object with extra keys is supposed to be valid

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have defined an interface:

```
interface Value {
  label: string;
}
```

I then define a variable:

```
const exactValue = { label: 'foo' };
const tooManyButValidValue = { label: 'foo', extra: true };
```

We can see this is valid because I can create an array of this:

```
const validValues: Value[] = [exactValue, tooManyButValidValue];
```

As seen here in TS Playground - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcUG8BQyyGcARhBgFzIDOYUoA5gNz4C+++CA9iHchAAeiMOmwoAvMlzEyFagHIY3bguRtWPPmGRgVAWTggAngCEsozMAAmYnMikyS5KsiUqFAGgGD6cavT2Gpxa-ABuVraYODTUdhAA2gC6DsgJQiLx3nrchibmlhg28UnMQA

However when I try to add `:Value` to tooManyButValidValue it fails -

```
const tooManyButValidValue: Value = { label: 'foo', extra: true };
```

as seen in screenshot below, and TS playground here - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcUG8BQyyGcARhBgFzIDOYUoA5gNz4C+++CA9iHchAAeiMOmwoAvMlzEyFagHIY3bguRtWPPmGRgVAWTggAngCEsozMAAmYnNTuTps8lWRKVCgDQDB9ONT0OOqsXLz8AG5Wtpg4NA6xEADaALrIUklCIo4+etyGJuaWGDaOKcxAA

Why is this the case? How to tell typescript that `tooManyButValidValue` is a valid value?

---

The above is a simple case, my exact case is I am using react. And i have defined an interface like this:

```
interface Props {
    values: Value[]
}
```

Then when I do:

```
<Component values={[
    { label: 'foo', bar: true },
    { label: 'qux', baz: true },
]} />
```

It complains. Because it is doing:

```
const values: Values = [
    { label: 'foo', bar: true },
    { label: 'qux', baz: true },
];
```

[image]

Comment: The issue is that "fresh" object literals are treated differently; they undergo [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).

Comment: I would amend to @jcalz saying it is not an "issue", it is an explicit "feature" that helps developer to avoid common errors.

Comment: Interesting thank you both.